# iOS make VPN server address variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, vpn

I am creating a custom VPN app for iOS. I already have a simple VPN App with a switch and connecting/disconnecting works.

My goal is to have the VPN host variable thus I can select the corresponding server dynamically in the app, e.g., one in the US, one in France, one in Australia.

What I tried is to set the protocol config server address initially to "none" and change it accordingly to the selection within the my connect method:

```
func connect() {
    NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { error in
        guard error == nil else {
            NSLog("Failed loading preferences: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if (NEVPNManager.shared().protocolConfiguration == nil) {
            NSLog("Not installed")
            return
        }

        NSLog("serveraddress: \(String(describing: NEVPNManager.shared().protocolConfiguration?.serverAddress))")
        NEVPNManager.shared().protocolConfiguration?.serverAddress = "xxxxxxx"
        NSLog("serveraddress: \(String(describing: NEVPNManager.shared().protocolConfiguration?.serverAddress))")

        do {
            let options: [String: NSObject] = [
                NEVPNConnectionStartOptionUsername : "xxxxxx" as NSObject,
                NEVPNConnectionStartOptionPassword : "xxxxxx" as NSObject
            ]
            try NEVPNManager.shared().connection.startVPNTunnel(options: options)
            return
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Failed to start vpn: \(error)")
            return
        }
    })
}
```

This does not work and the VPN connection status gets stuck in "connecting".

So my question is how to make the server address variable?
Also what is the remote identifier for?

Comment: Is your application subscribed to the `NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange` notification?

Comment: Yes it is, NEVPNStatusDidChange notifications work. My question is about why I cannot connect when I set the server address here in the loadFromPreferences context but can when I set it in the initial one to request access to the VPN settings.

Answer (score 0):

In our product , We use config file(json/plist/txt), When extension make a connect call , auto connect selected server!